# django | Returned from FormWizard: [{'sender': u'test@test.com', 'subject': u'test'}, {'message': u'ok'}]

Tags: python, django

From this class:

```
class ContactWizard(FormWizard):
def done(self, request, form_list):
    return render_to_response('done.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
    })
```

I'm returning to done.html, which is simply:

```
<u1>
{{ form_data }}
</u1>
```

The output that is returned is  `[{'sender': u'test@test.com', 'subject': u'test'}, {'message': u'ok'}]`

How can I access just a single value?  Nothing works for me. I would have guessed that I could use `form_data['sender']...` What is this data type?

Answer (score 0):

form_data is a list of dicts.

```
{{ form_data.0.sender }}
```